# Building a QGIS 3.10 script without an output layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

So I've read about the processing scripts you can do in QGIS 3. However, there seems to be no way of just modifying a layer directly and instead I have to have an output layer, which I do not want.

If you check at *https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/134*, they say that

> it's best to have at least one out always defined to avoid fully black box algorithms if none is set. If a output isn't defined it will raise an exception.

The problem I have with that is because the module I am working on right now only adds fields and changes values in the attribute table. The output layer I would create would need to be deleted right after because there would be nothing in it.

All I want is the Input layer and make my changes within that layer, the output is a hindrance. If there is indeed no way to not have an output I would like to know if there's a way for the output to be just a log for example or something like that that way at least it could be of some use.

Comment: Some tools indeed have a html output for example.

Comment: You have several examples from QGIS source code. For instance, have a look at [Select by expression](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b6a7a1070329a1f167341e3187781954d28f2f39/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SelectByExpression.py) and [Define projection](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b6a7a1070329a1f167341e3187781954d28f2f39/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/DefineProjection.py). Here [an example](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b6a7a1070329a1f167341e3187781954d28f2f39/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/ImportIntoPostGIS.py) that returns an empty dict. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer` as input in `initAlgorithm` method and use `self.parameterAsVectorLayer` to get the layer reference in `processAlgorithm` method. Then you can use methods and properties of  `QgsVectorLayer` class.

This is a sample script which gets a vector layer you specified, adds/populates a field and returns the layer itself.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsField,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer)

class TestAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(self.INPUT, self.tr('Input layer')))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        input_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

        ### PROCESS ###
        input_layer.startEditing()
        input_layer.addAttribute(QgsField("Test_Field", 10, len=50)) # 10: Type String
        for feature in input_layer.getFeatures():
            feature["Test_Field"] = "TEST"
            input_layer.updateFeature(feature)
        input_layer.commitChanges()
        ###############

        return {"OUTPUT": input_layer.id()}

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return TestAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'test'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Test')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example Scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'example_scripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr('')
```

I am not sure if this is the best approach.